# php - How can I make the hosting site's editor see the source code in my text area?

Tags: php

Sorry if the title is ambiguous, I don't really know how to ask, so I'm just going to explain.

I'm a beginner and I'm currently working on my bachelor final project. A website like codecademy or such.

I have a page in which I want to test the user into inputting the correct lines of code in the designated text area. The code works just fine on localhost, but I've hosted my site on a free hosting site called byethost.com

The code is as follows: (apologies for the mess I'm about to leave)

```
<p>Fill in the gaps. Make sure to leave no empty space and to not delete/change anything else or it won't work!!!</p>
<form method="post" >
<textarea style=" height: 400px;width:400px;" name="sourceCode" id="sourceCode" value="sourceCode"><html>
<head>
<title>This is the title</title>

<body>
<h1>This is a heading<h1>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
</body>
</html></textarea>
<input style="float:right; margin-top:400px; display:inline-block;" type="submit" name="submit" style="background:url(/Images/submitbtn.png);" value="submit"/>

</form>
<a  href="htmlles3.php"><button style="float:left; margin-top:2%; display:inline-block;" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Back</button></a>
</div>

<footer><p>para </p></footer>
<script src="tryit.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
<?php
$a = '<html>
<head>
<title>This is the title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>';


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


if ($a == $_POST['sourceCode']) {

} else {

return;
}
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$sql = "UPDATE user SET points = points + 5 WHERE id = '" . $id . "'";

if ($mysqli->query($sql)) {
redirect_to("profile.php?id={$_SESSION['user_id']}");
}
}
?>
```

Like I said, very messy, the problem is in the hosting site, it takes $_POST['sourceCode'] and processes it as a string with no html tags. So $a will never equal it, making my code not work.

If I could get some feedback on this, I would immensely appreciate it.

Thank you.

#### UPDATE

Thank you for your answers. I'm not really sure about how to go with this, but this is what I've got in the end:

```
<?php
echo '<div id="tutorial-content" style="display:inline-block;">';


error_reporting(0);
echo "<p>Fill in the gaps. Make sure to leave no empty space and to not 
 delete/change anything else or it won't work!!!</p>";
echo '<form method="post" >';
$html = html_entity_decode($_POST['sourceCode']);
 echo '<textarea style=" height: 400px;width:400px;" name="sourceCode" 
id="sourceCode">'.htmlentities($html).'</textarea>';



echo'<input style="float:right; margin-top:400px; display:inline-block;" 
type="submit" name="submit" style="background:url(/Images/submitbtn.png);" value="submit"/>';


echo '<a  href="htmlles3.php"><button style="float:left; margin-top:2%; display:inline-block;" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Back</button></a>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</form>';
echo '<footer><p>para </p></footer>
<script src="tryit.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>';

$a = '<html>
<head>
<title>This is the title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>';


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
var_dump($html);

if ($a == $html) {

} else {

return;
}
 $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$sql = "UPDATE user SET points = points + 5 WHERE id = '" . $id . "'";

if ($mysqli->query($sql)) {
redirect_to("profile.php?id={$_SESSION['user_id']}");
}
}
?>
```

I've tried my best implementing what you've said and it's still the same thing. var_dump() still gives me the string without the html tags.

Comment: If the user types HTML code into the text area, it will be included in `$_POST['sourceCode']`

Comment: You should be using HTML entities inside your `<textarea>`, not actual HTML tags. This is just a guess, but maybe the browser is stripping those, not PHP. Also, the values are never going to be equal because in your PHP you have only one line break after the `<title>` tag, but in the HTML you have 2 line breaks.

Comment: Thank you, I've put it all in php tags for now. I implemented htmlentities() and html_entity_decode() as per the answer I got below and I updated my answer. It still doesn't work, though

Comment: first of all, do not turn error reporting off - you will experiance strange behaviour without clues why. before you use `$_POST['sourceCode']` you need to check if its set or not... do it like this: `if(isset($_POST['sourceCode'])){ /* use here */ }`

Comment: and you need to realize that html use browser to know how draw page so if you want to show text which contains tags you need to convert special characters to entities which represent those characters to be able show them as text... so now `var_dump` is universal function to show content of varible but if variable contains html then it will be drawen as html in browser (if you look at source code of the page you will see raw data and it will be there)

Comment: instead of `var_dump($a);` use: `var_dump(htmlentities($a));`...

Comment: `htmlentities` - convert html to be able to ses it as text in browser (change html special characters to entities), `html_entity_decode` - oposite function

Answer (score 0):

when you output `<` to html, browser take it as start of tag, whole problem here is that you don't use entities so take a look at [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)
 and [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

use them like:

```
echo '<textarea>'.htmlentities($html).'</textarea>';
//and
$html = html_entity_decode($_POST['sourceCode']);
```

also textarea don't have attribute value...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've updated my post above with your code implemented, please give me some feedback on it.